# AutoHistory table data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How do I migrate data from a single table to a History table checking a field?

I want to migrate rows with an expiration value checking out their CreationDate.

I just looked to Audit and EntityFrameWork.AutoHistory but I cannot realize how to check data for every entry in a certain time lapse and how to migrate that (inserting into History table and removing from the Origin table).

I am in EntityFramework Core 2.1.8 with AspNetCore 2.1.

Comment: `Update-Database -Verbose`?

Comment: I need any kind of clock that Updates my Db at runtime instead of doing it manually.

Comment: You can override your SaveChanges method in DbContext class